# Restrict density in API 7

Tags: android

How can I restrict density in Manifest in early version than API 9. As I know since this API there is a tag

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize=["small" | "normal" | "large" | "xlarge"]
            android:screenDensity=["ldpi" | "mdpi" | "hdpi" | "xhdpi"] />
    ...
</compatible-screens>
```

But in early versions I can only restrict screen size with

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
    />
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple set your `target SDK` version to 9, and `minSDK` version to whatever you want. This way the density will be restricted on devices with API version 9 and higher, and on devices with API version lower than 9 only the screen size parameter will be checked. AFAIK, there's no other way to resolve this problem.